# Term of winning mining

Tags: mining, network

I'm new to the ethereum network and read official documents on the site(https://ethereum.org/).

But,I could't find out the term of of winnning mining like getting leading　4-zero or 6-zero hash.

Before I read books which is said that miners have to try to find appropriate nonce to meet it.

Now is that changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributing an answer to Ethereum Stack Exchange!

I found the answer.

https://ethereum.org/ja/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pow/mining-algorithms/ethash/